# Insert into n-ary tree using Queue

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree

I have a simple n-ary (3 child nodes maximum) whereby the first node inserted will be the root. Before, I add any other node, I have to search the tree and insert as a child node from a previously inserted node, if a condition is meet.
My insertion methods is overloaded for first insertion and subsequent insertions.

I was able to insert the first node using this method:

```
void Tree::AddSkill(char* name, char* desc, int level)
{
    Skill s(name, desc, level);
    Node * newNode = new Node(s);
    //newNode->aSkill = Skill(name, desc, level);

    newNode->parent = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i<CHILD_MAX; i++)
    {
        newNode->children[i] = NULL;
    }

    if (this->root == NULL)
    {
        this->root = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        this->root->parent = newNode;
        newNode->children[0] = this->root;
        this->root = newNode;
    }
}
```

I'm having a few issues with subsequent insertion into the tree,
Here is the code I have so far:

```
void Tree::AddSkill(char* name, char* desc, int level, char* parentName)
{
    if (this->root == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Error: no nodes in tree.\n";
        return;
    }

    Node* node = NULL;
    Skill s(name, desc, level);
    Node * child = new Node(s);
    while (root != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(child->aSkill.GetName(), parentName) == 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < CHILD_MAX; i++)
            {
                if (node->children[i] == NULL)
                {
                    child->aSkill = s;
                    child->parent = node;
                    node->children[i] = child;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the code through VS Debugger, the while loop in the second `AddSkill` method repeats endlessly.
I'm not so sure what I'm doing wrong or what concept I need to implement, any help will be appreciated.

P.S. This is an Homework (Not sure what the appropriate tag is).

Update:
I have tried to implement the overloaded `AddSkill()` using Queue.
This is what I've tried with it.

```
void SkillTree::AddSkill(char* name, char* desc, int level, char* parentName)
{
    if (this->root == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Error: no nodes in tree.\n";
        return;
    }  
    queue<Node*> q;
    q.push(this->root);
    while (!q.empty())
    {
        Node * n = q.front();
        q.pop();    
        if (strcmp(n->aSkill.GetName(), parentName) == 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i<CHILD_MAX; i++)
            {
                if (n->children[i] == NULL)
                {
                    Skill s(name, desc, level);
                    Node * child = new Node(s);
                    //When I comment out the next 3 lines, program does not crash. Not sure what the problem is here.
                    child->aSkill = s;
                    child->parent = n;
                    n->children[i] = child;
                    return;
                }
            }
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i<CHILD_MAX; i++)
        {
            if (n->children[i] != NULL)
            {
                q.push(n->children[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Skill Class

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Skill.h"
Skill::Skill()
{
    name = NULL;
    desc = NULL;
    level = 0;
}

Skill::Skill(char* name, char* desc, int level) : level(level), name(new char[strlen(name) + 1]), desc(new char[strlen(desc) + 1])
{
    strcpy_s(this->name, (strlen(name) + 1), name);
    strcpy_s(this->desc, (strlen(desc) + 1), desc);
}

Skill::Skill(const Skill& aSkill)
{
    this->name = new char[strlen(aSkill.name) + 1];
    strcpy_s(this->name, (strlen(aSkill.name) + 1), aSkill.name);

    this->level = aSkill.level;

    this->desc = new char[strlen(aSkill.desc) + 1];
    strcpy_s(this->desc, (strlen(aSkill.desc) + 1), aSkill.desc);
}

Skill& Skill::operator=(const Skill& aSkill)
{
    if (this == &aSkill)
        return *this;
    else
    {
        delete[] name;
        delete[] desc;

        name = new char[strlen(aSkill.name) + 1];
        strcpy_s(name, (strlen(aSkill.name) + 1), aSkill.name);

        desc = new char[strlen(aSkill.desc) + 1];
        strcpy_s(name, (strlen(aSkill.desc) + 1), aSkill.desc);

        level = aSkill.level;

        return *this;
    }
}

Skill::~Skill()
{
    delete[] name;
    delete[] desc;
}

char* Skill::GetName() const
{
    return name;
}
char* Skill::GetDesc() const
{
    return desc;
}
int Skill::GetLevel() const
{
    return level;
}

void Skill::Display(ostream& out)
{
    out << "- " << GetName() << " -- " << GetDesc() << " [Lvl: " << GetLevel() << "]\n";
}
```

Node:

```
    Skill aSkill;
    Node* parent;
    Node* children[CHILD_MAX];
    Node() : parent(NULL)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < CHILD_MAX; i++)
        {
            children[i] = NULL;
        }
    };

    Node(const Skill& n) : aSkill(n), parent(NULL)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < CHILD_MAX; i++)
        {
            children[i] = NULL;
        }
    };
```

Here is an extract from `main()`

```
SkillTree student("Student");
    student.Display(cout);

    student.AddSkill("Alphabet","Mastery of letters and sounds",0);
    student.Display(cout);

    student.AddSkill("Reading","The ability to read all manner of written material",1,"Alphabet");
    student.AddSkill("Writing","The ability to put your thoughts on paper",1,"Alphabet");
    student.Display(cout); 
student.AddSkill("Speed Reading Level 1","Read any text twice as fast as normal",5,"Reading");
student.AddSkill("Speed Reading Level 2","Read any text four times as fast as normal",10,"Speed Reading Level 1");
student.AddSkill("Memorization","Memorize average sized texts",10,"Reading");
student.AddSkill("Massive Memorization","Memorize large sized texts",20,"Memorization");
student.AddSkill("Spell Writing","The ability to write spells",5,"Writing");
student.AddSkill("History","The ability to write (and rewrite) history",10,"Writing");
student.AddSkill("Written Creation","The ability to write things into reality",20,"History");
student.Display(cout);
```

The two functions that `student.Display(cout);` calls are as follow

```
    void Tree::Display(ostream& out)
{
    out << "Skill Tree: " << title << "\n";
    if (this->root == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Empty\n";
        return;
    }
    else
        Display_r(out, this->root, 1);
}

void Tree::Display_r(ostream& out, Node* n, int depth)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<depth; i++)
    {
        out << "  ";
    }
    n->aSkill.Display(out);

    for (int i = 0; i<CHILD_MAX; i++)
    {
        if (n->children[i] != NULL)
        {
            Display_r(out, n->children[i], depth + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

If I comment out a section of code in the Queue implementation of `AddSkill()`, I get no error.

Comment: It loops endlessly because `root is never NULL`.  What other reason could there be?  If the question is "why root never becomes NULL", then that should have been addressed in your original design (hopefully you did this on paper first before writing the code).

Comment: Just a hint, add some debugging messages when you check for a validation so you know where it reaches and where it doesn't.

Comment: You never change root in your loop, so the while condition is always true.

Comment: The problem of your edited code is probably related to the Skill class.  Can you show us the Skill constructor and the Skill copy constructor and the Skill assignment operator, please ?

Comment: @Christophe added Skill ctor, copy ctor and assignment operator.

Comment: @hello Skill seems clean.  I suppose Node contains a member of type `Skill`  which would be clean as well.  When does the program crash ?  In the middle of the additions ?  Or at the end when the tree (aka nodes) are destroyed ?

Comment: @Christophe I added more code. The program crashes in the middle. 
If I call `Display()`, I get an empty tree - correct. When I execute `AddSkill()` used to make root of the tree, it executes well, if I call `Display(), I get the right message, but when I insert child nodes, I get no error until I try to display tree.

Comment: Ok !  The node constructor doesn't initialize the member pointers.  Read [this article](http://blogs.microsoft.com/cybertrust/2012/03/08/guarding-against-uninitialized-class-member-pointers/), make sure every pointer is set to null, and then it should work

Comment: @Christophe I updated Node constructors. While debugger was stepping through each line of code, I get no error on both `AddSkill()` and `Display()` methods, but on exit, `dbgheap.c` file opens up and then program crashes with `Tree.exe has triggered a breakpoint`.

Comment: Ok, so AddSkill (the main reason of the question) works.  The fact that it crashes on exist shows that there's somwhere memory corruption going on or dangling pointers (on exit, main objects are destructed). And this can happen anywhere.  You should consider posting the complete code on [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first `AddSkill()` you insert the new node on the top of the tree, making it the new root.

In the second `AddSkill()` you intend to insert the new node as child of a parent skill. The approach seems to be:

- check that there is at least one node in the tree (initial if)
- traverse the tree to find the parrent node ( `while` loop )
- if the parent is found, find the first empty child to insert the new skill (inner `for` loop)

**What are the problems ?**

THere are several flaws in your algorithm:

- you loop on `root` not null.  As the tree is not empty here, and as you don't delete any node, this condition will remain true, allowing for an endless loop.
- then you check if the new child's name corresponds to the parentname.  I assume that this will be false most of the case (otherwhise you'd need one parameter less).  So this will ensure that the loop is endless.
- later you assume that `node` is the current node, and you insert the new `child` into `node`'s children.  This code is not exectuted. Fortunately:  it would be undefined behaviour, because you've set `node` to `NULL` and never changed this value.

**How to solve it ?**

To do this right, you'd have to start with `node` at `root`, then check if the node's name matches `parentname`, and if yes, insert the child as you did.

There's a last problem however. A rather important one. The structure of your algorithm works for a linked list traversal, but not a [tree traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal).  The tree traversal algorithm requires either a stack/list to keep track of all the branches to explore,  or a recursive approach.

Here some code (*sorry, I've replaced `char*` with `string` and used `vector<Node*>` instead of `Node*[]`*), using an auxiliary overload of `AddSkill()`, to perform the recursive search:

```
// replaces the former one that you had
void Tree::AddSkill(string name, string  desc, int level, string parentName)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Error: no nodes in tree.\n";
        return;
    }
    Skill s(name, desc, level);
    AddSkill(root, s, parentName); 
}

// auxiliary helper
void Tree::AddSkill(Node*node, Skill& s, string& parentName)
{
    if (node->sk.name == parentName) {  // if found, add the new node as childen
        Node * child = new Node(s);
        child->parent = node;
        node->children.push_back(child);
    }
    else {
        for (auto &x : node->children)   // for all the children 
            AddSkill(x, s, parentName);  // search recursively   
    }
}
```

And here an [online demo](https://ideone.com/6Fur4H) using shared pointers instead of raw pointers.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I updated before seeing your edit. I tried to implement`AddSkill()` using Queue. Please see my question update.

Comment: The edit is much better !  From the tree perspective, your algorithm seems to work well, and there's no reason for it to crash.  I suspect that in your `Skill` constructor you allocate and clone the c-strings and that you haven't defined an `operator=` for it.  So every assignment like `child->aSkill = s;` (which is by the way not needed, as your node constructor is already based on s) might create dangling pointers.